Places API text search not returning all locations of restaurant
For example:
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/textsearch/json?query=Rosie’s%20Burgers&location=43.5986168,-79.7835341&radius=50000&key=APIKEY
This call returns only 2 of the 4 locations within 50km. I'm having this issue with multiple restaurants. Doing the search in Google Maps returns all locations.
I tired Rosie's Burgers Restaurant as search and I got 3 results so it's a hit  or miss. I just want to be able to retieve all locations of a place within a defined area.

I tried to replicate and got the same behavior. Even properly encoding the apostrophe in "Rosie's" did not resolve the problem, and only two results were returned. However, using "Rosies Burgers" (without the apostrophe) in the query returned the four results. All four restaurants in question are actually named "Rosie's Burgers". So, due to these inconsistencies, you can report this as a bug on the Places API's public issue tracker: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues?q=componentid:188872
